# Firebase Angular2 - how to query and render lists without too much overhead

Tags: database, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In my application I have the following firebase posts structure:

```
posts: {
    text: ".."
    meta: {..}
    user: {
        id: "user1",
        username: ".."
    }
}
```

I'm using angularfire2.
So, to get all posts posted by specific user, I run the following query:

```
this.userPosts$ = this.af.database.list('/posts', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'user/id',
      equalTo: userId
    }
  }).map( (posts) => {
    return posts.map(post => Post.unpack(post));
  }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
```

I've heard that it's not very efficient, since every time something changes (even in a single post), the whole list is reloaded and, thus, re-rendered. And since I have likes and dislikes in my app, this is gonna happen pretty often. Basically every time someone likes a post, the whole list is reloaded for every user, if I'm not mistaken.

I know that there is a way to maintain a local copy of the list while listening  to firebase events: "child_added", "child_removed" and "child_changed".
However, if I attach these events to the queried list, they are going to fire each time something changes in the original posts list as a whole.

So, I am thinking what approach to take here. I might duplicate posts data into "user_posts" list in firebase if it is the only good choice. However, with this approach I feel that querying becomes almost useless and I lose flexibility. I started to use firebase just about a week ago, so I might still have some misunderstandings.

Comment: I've had a peek at AngularFire2's behaviour with long lists. I would not put any effort into this, if I were you, as the implementation is very fast and plays nice with Angular's change detection when the `preserveSnapshot` option is used. It's only when that option is not specified that the entire list appears to change. There should be something that can be done about this and I'm going to look into raising an issue and submitting a PR. After that, I'll answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When looking into this question, I discovered [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/791) with the `FirebaseListObservable` implementation when `preserveSnapshot` was `false` - the default behaviour. Each time the observable emitted an array of unwrapped snapshots, the array elements were different instances - even if the elements themselves had not changed. And this resulted in much less efficient change detection.

A [fix has been merged](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/792) and will be included in the next release of AngularFire2 (that is, the release that follows `2.0.0-beta.7`) - which [should be soon](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/804#issuecomment-277802274).

With the fix, if Angular's `OnPush` change detection is used, AngularFire2's `FirebaseListObservable` is very fast and efficient regarding DOM updates.

I usually split the components into [container and presentational components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), with the container component holding the observable and with the presentational component using `OnPush` change detection.

The container component would look something like this:

```ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2";

@Component({
  selector: "items-container",
  template: `<items-component [items]="items | async"></items-component>`
})
export class ItemsContainer {

  private items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(private angularFire: AngularFire) {
    this.items = angularFire.database.list("some/fast-changing/data", {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 1000
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And the presentational component would look something like this:

```ts
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: "items-component",
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item | json }}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class ItemsComponent {
  @Input() items: any[];
}
```

With this arrangement of components, Angular's `OnPush` change detection will ensure that only the elements that have actually changed will effect DOM updates. So even long, scrolling lists will be efficient and fast.

Another tip: a `FirebaseListObserable` that uses a limit query will sometimes emit two values when the underlying data changes. For example, when a new item is added to the database, a list that queries the 10 most recent items (using `limitToLast: 10`) will emit an array with the least recent item removed and will then immediately emit another with the most recent item added. If you don't want the first of those two arrays to be emitted, you can use the [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) operator:

```ts
import "rxjs/add/operator/auditTime";

this.items = angularFire.database.list("some/fast-changing/data", {
  query: {
    limitToLast: 10
  }
})
.auditTime(0);
```