# Optimal way to retrieve and view large amount of data in a Firebase list?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Having a Firebase List (with title, description, and Firebase storage image url) to show it on the template we usually use:

```
 constructor(
    private af: AngularFire
) {

this.blogs = this.af.database.list('\blogs');
```

---

```
    <div *ngFor='let blogItem of blogs | async'>
          <div  id="{{blogItem.$key}}">
            <img class="blogImage" [src]="blogItem.imageURL">
          </div>
      <span> {{blogItem.description}} </span>
    </div>
```

Using the above, do the job and show the data and also sync with the Firebase, but:

1. Its slow when show for the first time in the view, when I do refresh, the description came first then the images, so I see it like chunks? is this the correct way? Any performance issue?
2. When I suppose to use 'async' in the template?
3. Even if I moved the list retrieving part to a data service, the speed is the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Angular2 - how to query and render lists without too much overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777531/firebase-angular2-how-to-query-and-render-lists-without-too-much-overhead)